# Jetpack Compose CircularProgressIndicator counterclockwise direction

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using countdown (reverse counting) so need progress fill counterclockwise.
I see it doesn't have direction setting.
I've tried `Modifier.grapficsLayer(scaleX = -1f)`
or `Modifier.scale(x=-1f)` but it doesn't mirror CircularProgressIndicator on X axis.
Is there a way to change progress to counterclockwise / remove progress clockwise?

Comment: By default, the CircularProgressIndicator in Jetpack Compose progresses clockwise. However, you can achieve a counterclockwise progression by rotating the Canvas on which the progress is drawn.

Comment: Is there a short idiomatic way of doing so? That would be great answer.

Comment: `.scale(scaleX = -1f, scaleY = 1f)` looks fine to me

Comment: scale doesn't work for CirculatProgressIndicator, at least in preview. It is not mirrored.